# Catch Exceptions Globally using ElmahCore in Aspnet core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, elmah

I am using Aspnet core 3.0 and I have configured [ElmahCore](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore) for exception handling. however from their documentation, they advise to catch exceptions using

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    HttpContext.RiseError(new InvalidOperationException("Test"));
    ...
}
```

How can I configure Elmahcore to automatically catch and log all exceptions? or Do I have to write `HttpContext.RiseError` everytime I want to catch and log an exception?

Like Do I have to put `try catch` blocks for every `ActionResult` and call `HttpContext.RiseError()` in all of my catch blocks?

Is there a way that I can configure catching and logging of exceptions using ElmahCore globally?

Comment: You can try to create and configure a custom [exception filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-filters) globally, and handle error/exception in that global custom exception filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Fei-han's suggestion and this [global error handling link](https://scottsauber.com/2017/04/03/adding-global-error-handling-and-logging-in-asp-net-core/), I am able to log exceptions globally in my production environment. In Startup.cs file, I made sure that I have an `ExceptionHandler` configured when my application is running in production mode like

Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");  
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseElmah();

  //Other configurations
}
```

This ensures that whenever an uncaught exception has occurred, it will call the Error Action Method of Home Controller

Home Controller

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        var exceptionFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        if (exceptionFeature != null)
        {
            // Get the exception that occurred
            Exception exceptionThatOccurred = exceptionFeature.Error;
            //log exception using ElmahCore
            HttpContext.RiseError(exceptionThatOccurred);
        }

        //Return custom error page (I have modified the default html of
        //Shared>Error.cshtml view and showed my custom error page)
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
```

Now all of my exceptions are getting logged and I am also showing a customized error page in response to an exception.